# Accessing DOM elements outside of $(this).each function()

Tags: jquery

I have a div on a JSP that I want to populate when I mouse over items associated 
with a particular css class but it looks like I'm hitting a scope issue. Any idea
what I'm doing wrong?

JSP:
$('.hoverTrigger').myFunc();

Text goes here

JavaScript .js file referenced by JSP:

```
$.fn.myFunc = function(options) {
  $(this).each(function() {
    $this.hover(
       function() {
         // Want to set text in messageBox here but not working
         $('#messageBox').after("Hover IN").remove();
       },
       function() {
         // Want to set text in messageBox here but not working
         $('#messageBox').after("Hover OUT").remove();
       }
    );

  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `$(this).hover` instead of `$this.hover`. Also if you remove `#messageBox` on mouse in you will not be able to select it on mouse out.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).hover();`// should do the trick. or else you can cache the variable.

```
var currobj; 
 $(this).each(function() {
currobj=$(this)//cache the current object. and use it 
    $(currobj).hover(
       function() {
         // Want to set text in messageBox here but not working
         $('#messageBox').after("Hover IN").remove();
       },
       function() {
         // Want to set text in messageBox here but not working
         $('#messageBox').after("Hover OUT").remove();
       }
    );

  });
```